# UIImageView changed in all UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiimageview

I want to change a specific UIImageView inside a UITableViewCell with this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self updateTableView];
    //get and show the image at selected cell
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:UYLCellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    UYLTextCell *textCell = (UYLTextCell *)cell;
    textCell.testImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image280280.jpg"];

}
```

but what happened is some cell had their image View changed and it also takes time.

this is where I declared the UIImageView in the UITableViewCell class:

```
@interface UYLTextCell : UITableViewCell

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lineLabel;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *testImage;


@end
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're changing the information in an essentially-random cell instead of changing the information in your data source. You need logic within your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method that knows that this cell was selected, and then set the image in that method (or specifically reset the image if it should not be selected). Keep a BOOL value in your data source and set it when it is selected and then reload that cell.

Example:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self updateTableView];
    //get and show the image at selected cell
    dataSourceObjectForIndexPath.cellShouldBeSelected = YES;
    [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UYLTextCell *textCell = (UYLTextCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"whatever" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // set up your cell however it needs to be

    if(dataSourceObjectForIndexPath.cellShouldBeSelected)
    {
        textCell.testImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image280280.jpg"];
    }
    else
    {
        textCell.testImage.image = //whatever the default state is
    }

    return textCell;
}
```

Comment: what is dataSourceObjectForIndexPath.cellShouldBeSelected? is it an array? why is there no index number in this array? where should i decalre it?

Comment: It is simply an example of a BOOL value somewhere in your data source. For instance, if your table is populated by an array of custom objects, you could create a BOOL in that custom object to denote that it is selected. Alternatively, you could create an instance `NSIndexPath` variable that stores the selected index. But you need something that `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` can see to know the image needs to be set appropriately.

Comment: this still doesnt work. are you sure this is the way?

Answer (score 1):

This code is nonsense:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:UYLCellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

This `cell` is not the cell that was just selected, so who knows what cell it is, if any?

So what cell *was* just selected? It's this one:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```